# Google Earth Engine - Export image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I can't export PNG images with Google Earth Engine. I could export TIFF images with the code below but, they are entirely black.

```
// Load a landsat image and select three bands.
var landsat = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_123032_20140515')
  .select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);

// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([116.2621, 39.8412, 116.4849, 40.01236]);

// Retrieve the projection information from a band of the original image.
// Call getInfo() on the projection to request a client-side object containing
// the crs and transform information needed for the client-side Export function.
var projection = landsat.select('B2').projection().getInfo();

// Export the image, specifying the CRS, transform, and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: landsat,
  description: 'google_engine3',
  crs: projection.crs,
  crsTransform: projection.transform,
  region: geometry
});
```

Comment: I ran your code and the exported GeoTIFF looks just fine. What software do you use to visualize your image? You cannot export as a PNG, only GeoTIFF (and TFRecord, which doesn't make any sense for this).

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I use Gimp to visualize the image. Do you recommend another software ? I need the images in PNG or JPG format. Is there a way to convert them ?

Comment: You can open the image with QGIS (it's open source), select which bands to render and how to stretch them (right click on the layer, select Properties... > Symbology). When you're happy with how it looks, you can export (Project > Import/Export > Export Map to Image...).